# Branch-per-feature, Environment branches and Azure Pipelines

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

**Background:**

We have an in-house CI/CD tool based on [FAKE](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE) that performs the following workflow:

- user enters 2 parameters: `$source-branch` and `$target-environment`
- pull `master`
- pull `$source-branch`
- pull `$target-environment` (there is a git branch for every environment: `DEV`, `TEST`, etc, except for `PROD` which is hard-coded to `master`)
- create a temporary branch from `$target-environment` called `$target-environment-$current-date-$source-branch` (for instance `DEV-201811271840-SomeNewFeature`)
- merge master into temp branch
- merge `$source-branch` into temp branch
- execute build script
- deploy
- if deploy succeeds, then merge temp branch into `$target-environment`.
- delete temp branch

**Problem:**

Without getting into too much detail about the build/deploy steps (which are a whole different conversation) I'd like to know if/how can I replicate this workflow in Azure Pipelines.

It seems that all documentation and even all the options in the UI refer to a different use case.

We want to be able to push our feature branches, have them merged to the environment branches (and eventually to `master`) **after** they're deployed, and not before, which is why we're performing build/test/deploy steps in a temporary branch, which gets merged into `$environment` ONLY after the build/test/deploy steps succeed.

**Question:**

Is this even possible using Azure Pipelines without resorting to custom code? I haven't found any documentation about it and the options in the UI don't seem to help either.

Comment: It's an interesting question, I think actually you'll not replicate this exact workflow in Pipelines, nor should you want to as pipelines has strong concepts around the environments you deploy to. I suspect there's a solution around using pull requests on feature branches that then release based on pull request triggers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=vsts), but I have to admit my  experience here isn't enough to put this as a solid answer to your question.